# FTP Server setup: VM issues

Tags: linux, virtualbox, ftp

I have an Filezilla FTP server setup on my Windows 7 64-bit machine. I can access this server on the Windows 7 machine itself.

I have Oracle Virtualbox installed, with a RHEL 5 Guest OS using Host-only Adapter. How would i go about configuring access to the FTP server from this guest OS?

I can ping the guest OS from my host, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the firewall on the host machine, then attempt to connect to FTP again.

If this fails, it could be a problem relating to what IPs the FTP server is listening on (Although, I haven't seen this on Filezilla). The easiest thing to do in this case is to have the networking on the virtual machine set to Bridged mode, and then try again.

Comment: You are right, disabling the firewall solves the issue. Is there any easy way to configure firewall rules to allow any guest OS running on the host only adapter to access the FTP server? I am using Windows Firewall.

Comment: You can add a rule for FTP in Windows Firewall to accept the IP range of you VBox VMs, thus allowiing every vm to connect to your host.

Comment: Yep, as @Shadok said, you can do it per IP range... Personally, if you want other machines to be able to access the FTP server, I would create a rule for the filezilla application... If you need a guide on how to do this, let me know and I will give you instructions when I have a bit more time... (FYI, I don't advise dropping the firewall altogether, it is just the easiest way to diagnose issues such as what you were having).

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, i added an incoming/outgoing exception for the Filezilla server for the specific IP range.